# computational attempt on symmetric random walk

Tags: martingales

> Theorem: Let $X_{n}$ be a Markov chain with transition probability p and let $f\left ( x,n \right )$ be a function of the state x and the time n so that 
>   $f\left ( x,n \right )=\sum_{y \in Y}{}p\left ( x,y \right )f\left ( y,n+1 \right )$.
>   Then $M_{n}=f\left ( X_{n},n \right )$ is a Martingale with respect to $X_{n}$. In particular, if $h\left ( x \right )=\sum_{y \in Y}{}p\left ( x,y \right )h\left ( y \right )$, then $h\left ( X_{n} \right )$ is a martingale.

Question:

Let $Y_{1},\cdot \cdot \cdot$  be independent with $P\left ( Y_{i}=1 \right )=P\left ( Y_{i}=-1 \right )=\frac{1}{2}$
and let $X_{n}=X_{0}+Y_{1}+\cdot \cdot \cdot +Y_{n}$.
Then, $M_{n}=X_{n}^{2}-n$ is a Martingale wrt $X_{n}$

Attempt:

Let $f\left ( x,n \right )=x^{2}-n=h\left ( x \right )$.

It suffices to show that $\sum{y \in Y}{}p\left ( x,y \right )h\left ( y \right ) =x^{2}-n$ by the theorem.

Now,

$p\left ( x,y \right )=\begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} &y=x+1  & \\ 
 \frac{1}{2}& y=x-1 & \\ 
0 &y\neq x-1 , y\not\neq x+1 & 
\end{Bmatrix}$

so

$\sum_{y \in Y}{}p\left ( x,y \right )h\left ( y \right ) =\frac{1}{2}\left ( x+1 \right )^{2}-n+\frac{1}{2}\left ( x-1 \right )^{2}-n$

author's attempt:

[image]

Why does the author's attempt differs from mine?

I'm puzzled.